# Log in not working using a Google account

Tags: bug, android-app

It said cannot find mismatch id.

Now I am logged using a Facebook account.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: Redmi Note 3
- OS Version: 7.1.2 (f31aab0341)